# Хочу при клике менять цвет текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите, при клике на блок с классом `row` менялся цвет текста этого блока,сделал эту задачу другим способом но очень длинным, щяс хочу сократить код;

[CSS можете не смотреть все правильно](https://jsfiddle.net/28r8es7n/2/)

```js
var sel1 = $('.row').attr('tabindex', 0);

// sel2 = $('.row2').attr('tabindex', 2),
// sel3 = $('.row3').attr('tabindex', 3),
// sel4 = $('.row4').attr('tabindex', 4),
// sel5 = $('.row5').attr('tabindex', 5),
// sel6 = $('.row6').attr('tabindex', 6),
// sel7 = $('.row7').attr('tabindex', 7),
// sel8 = $('.row8').attr('tabindex', 8);

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

  sel1 = $('.row[i]').attr('tabindex', [i]);

  sel1.focusin(function() {
    sel1.find('h3').css('color', '#3971ff');
  })
  sel1.focusout(function() {
    sel1.find('h3').css('color', '#4c4c4c');
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /*Firefox 1-3*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari */
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /*Firefox 1-3*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari */
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}


/*****Sidebar******/

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidebar h3 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 50px 30px 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #3971ff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
}

.s-menu {
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
  margin-bottom: -9999px;
}

.s-menu li {
  padding: 18px 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.s-menu li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.s-menu a {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-line {
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-line.active {
  width: 28px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

.s-menu li a.active {
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}


/******Sections*******/

.content {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/******Section Header*******/

.header {
  background-color: #EAEBED;
  height: 582px;
}

img.profile-img {
  margin: 125px;
}

.header-text {
  margin-top: -450px;
  margin-left: 450px;
}

.header-text h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

.header-text h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin: 0;
}

.header-text h1 span {
  color: #3971ff;
}

.header-text h4 {
  color: #3971ff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.header-text p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.header-text span {
  color: #3971ff;
}

.header-select {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin-right: 86px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-select:hover {
  color: #3971ff;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.down-line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
}

.header-select:hover .down-line {
  width: 120px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/******Skills*******/

.skills {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 220px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.skills h2 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.vector-line {
  width: 70px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
}

.vector-circle {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3971ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.circleInner {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}


/*****ProgressBar*****/

.progress {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #B0C6FF;
}

.bar {
  background-color: #3971FF;
}

.skills .column1 p,
.column2 p {
  margin: 25px 0 -20px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.skills .column1 span,
.column2 span {
  padding-left: 91%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#adobe {
  width: 30%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971FF;
}

#html {
  width: 90%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971FF;
}

#drupal {
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
}

#sketch {
  width: 45%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
}

#wordpress {
  width: 85%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
}

#shopify {
  width: 59%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
}

.column1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}

.column2 {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/******EDU*******/

.edu {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  padding-left: 220px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.edu h2 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin-top: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 48%;
}

.row p {
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin: 7px 0;
}

.row p:last-child {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

.row h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.row p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row3,
.row4 {
  display: inline-block;
}


/******Experience*******/

.exp {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 220px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.exp h2 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin-top: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 48%;
}

.row p {
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin: 7px 0;
}

.row p:last-child {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

.row h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.row p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.row5,
.row6 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row7,
.row8 {
  display: inline-block;
}


/******Project*******/

.project {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  padding-left: 220px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.project h2 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.inputfile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cards {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}

.cards img {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.lab {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding-bottom: 119px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.lab:hover {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.lab:hover img.plus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cards h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.cards p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

img.plus {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -175px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/*******Posts*******/

.post {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 220px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.post h2 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/******Post*******/

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.wrapper p {
  margin: 0;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}

.tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4c4c4c;
  width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.tab_content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper .active {
  color: #3971ff;
}

.wrapper .tab.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3971ff;
  background: url(images/mark.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.tab_item img {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 25px 70px 25px 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.tab-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: left;
}

.tab-text h3 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-text p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tab-text a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-text a:hover {
  color: #3971ff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3971ff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .header-text h1 {
    font-size: 38px;
  }
  .header-text h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .header-text h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  .header-text p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
  }
  img.profile-img {
    margin: 172px;
    max-width: 24%;
  }
  .cards img {
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: block;
  }
  img.plus {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -175px;
  }
  /*****Post*******/
  .tab-text p {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    min-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar h3 {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
  .sidebar h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    border: 0;
  }
  .s-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -65px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .left-line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #3971ff;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .s-menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 13px;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  /******Sections******/
  .sections {
    padding-top: 71px;
  }
  img.profile-img {
    max-width: 22%;
    margin: 116px 0 100px 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .header-text {
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .header-text h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .header-text h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .header-text h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
  }
  .header-text p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .header-select {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  /*****Skills*****/
  .skills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .skills h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  /*****.Active******/
  .left-line.active.animated.fadeInDown {
    width: auto;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .s-menu li a.active {
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: #4c4c4c;
  }
  /*******Education********/
  .edu {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .edu h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .edu .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .row {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .row p {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .row h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  /*******Experience********/
  .exp {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .exp h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .exp .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .row {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .row p {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .row h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  /******Project******/
  .project {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .project h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .project .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .cards img {
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: block;
  }
  img.plus {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -175px;
  }
  /*****Post*******/
  .post {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .post h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .post .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .tab_item img {
    padding: 25px 60px 25px 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .tab-text p {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  img.profile-img {
    max-width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .header-text {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 50px;
  }
  /*****Menu******/
  .sidebar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  }
  .sidebar h4 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .s-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .s-menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: -13px 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .s-menu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .left-line {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .down-line {
    display: none;
  }
  .left-line {
    height: 1px;
    width: auto;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .left-line.active {
    width: 40px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .s-menu li a.active {
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: #4c4c4c;
  }
  /****** Project*******/
  .cards img {
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: block;
  }
  img.plus {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -175px;
  }
  /******Post*******/
  .tab_item img {
    padding: 25px 60px 25px 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .tab-text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .tab-text p {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .tab-text a:hover {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /***Skilss****/
  .skills .column1 span,
  .column2 span {
    padding-left: 85%;
  }
  .skills {
    padding: 0 10px 70px 10px;
  }
  .column1,
  .column2 {
    width: 47%;
  }
  /*****Education******/
  .edu {
    padding: 0 10px 70px 10px;
  }
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .row h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .row p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  /****EXperience*****/
  .exp {
    padding: 0 10px 70px 10px;
  }
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .row h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .row p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  /****** Project*******/
  .cards {
    width: 49%;
  }
  .cards p {
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  .cards img {
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: block;
  }
  img.plus {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -175px;
  }
  /*****Post******/
  .post {
    padding: 0 10px 70px 10px;
  }
  .tabs {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .tab {
    padding: 0 10px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
  }
  .tab_item img {
    padding: 25px 40px 25px 40px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cards {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .lab {
    width: 96%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  /*****Post******/
  .wrapper {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .wrapper span {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .tabs {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .tab {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4c4c4c;
    padding: 13px 0 5px 0;
  }
  .tab_item img {
    padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;
    max-width: 35%;
  }
  .tab-text {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .tab-text p {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .header-text {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .header-select {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .down-line {
    display: none;
  }
  /****Skills***/
  .column1,
  .column2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .skills .column1 p,
  .column2 p {
    margin: 16px 0 -25px 0px;
  }
  /*****Edu******/
  .row {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  /*****Exp******/
  .row {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  /*****Post*****/
  .tab_item img {
    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="edu">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>EDUCATION <span class="vector-line"></span>
      <span class="vector-circle">
      <span class="circleInner"></span>
      </span>
    </h2>

    <div class="row1 row" tabindex="1">
      <h3>01 UNIVERSITY OF DESIGN</h3>
      <p>MASTER DEGREE OF DESIGN</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row2 row" tabindex="2">
      <h3>02 DEGREE OF DESIGN</h3>
      <p>MASTER DEGREE OF DESIGN</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row3 row" tabindex="3">
      <h3>03 VISUAL ART AND DESIGN</h3>
      <p>MASTER DEGREE OF DESIGN</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row4 row" tabindex="4">
      <h3>04 ANIMATIONS AND DESIGN</h3>
      <p>MASTER DEGREE OF DESIGN</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Education -->

<div class="exp">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>EXPERIENCE <span class="vector-line"></span>
      <span class="vector-circle">
      <span class="circleInner"></span>
      </span>
    </h2>

    <div class="row5 row" tabindex="5">
      <h3>05 BASUNDHARA GROUP</h3>
      <p>UI & UX DESIGNER</p>
      <p>Session: 2010 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row6 row" tabindex="6">
      <h3>06 DEVISERWEB</h3>
      <p>CO-FOUNDER AND COD</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – present</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row7 row" tabindex="7">
      <h3>07 ENVATO STUDIO</h3>
      <p>EXCLUSIVE AUTHOR</p>
      <p>Session: 2011 – PRESENT</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row8 row" tabindex="8">
      <h3>08 GOOGLEDESIGN</h3>
      <p>UI & UX DESIGNER</p>
      <p>Session: 2012 – 2013</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of printing an typesetting dustry. Lorem Ipsum the industry's dummy.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Experience -->
```

Comment: `$('.row[i]')` ???

Comment: я хотел как бы не задать 8 раз $('.row1'),$('.row2').... нахимичил неправильно ))

Comment: почитайте про селекторы jQuery

Comment: спасибо но решить задачу сможете?

Comment: э-э-э, нет, так дело не пойдет :).

Comment: Почему?? :D ну хоть дайте направление

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
$('.row').on('click', function(){
$('p', this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```js
$( ".row" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "red" );
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">123 456 789</div>
<div class="row">123 456 789</div>
<div class="row">123 456 789</div>
<div class="row">123 456 789</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое про это не знал но если вы сможете помогите сделать мое задание с циклом `for()`

Answer (score 2):

Короче не придумаешь!

```
<p onclick="this.style.color='blue'">HI</p>
```

Comment: Придумал: можно убрать `this.`

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid;
}

button:active {
    position: гelative;
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button>
    click me
</button>
```